# Pandas adding `.1` suffix to column names

Tags: python, pandas

I have an excel workbook with identically structured tables on the same sheet.  I have made a loop to read them in:

```
for usecols in['A:L','N:Y']:
    df = pd.read_excel(r"Frequency_CI_extracted.xlsx", 
                       usecols=usecols, skiprows=3, 
                       sheet_name = 'Quantiles_CI_inches')
```

The resulting data frame for the first iteration (i.e. `usecols="A:L"`) returns a data frame with the headers in the excel workbook.  When the loop is on its second iteration, the resulting data frame has a `.1` suffix one each column name.

[image]
Can anyone explain this behavior?

```
pd.__version__
Out[9]: '1.0.3'
```

Comment: You data may have duplicated column names, which is discouraged by pandas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens when you have two identical column names in a dataframe. That's why the second iteration is adding `.1`

Answer (score 1):

This happened in my code when I had a capitalized version of the column name being added after the lower case version, then forced ALL column names to lowercase.

```
df.columns = ['this', 'that', 'thethird']
df['theThird'] = 99
df.columns = df.columns.str.lower()
```

> df.columns

gives

> ['this', 'that', 'thethird', 'thethird.1']

check that there isn't some sort of column name adjustment like this happening in another function or being called between reading column names

Comment: IMO pandas should warn about this